# Can I return a default search radius form the Google Maps API based on the search query?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Here's what I need to do:

Say I search Google maps for france, and then for Rhode island. The radius of the map search results is much smaller for Rhode island than it is for france.

Is there a way I can get this radius information bases on a given search query from the Google Maps API?

Comment: There's a `viewport` returned in the results. See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry What issues are you having with that?

Comment: Looks like that's exactly what I need! Thanks! :D I didn't know the term they use is "viewport" so I didn't really know what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `viewport` which is returned in the Geocoder results.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry